# Batch Script or PowerShell script to read the multiple values from text file and insert into variables

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am looking for a batch script or PowerShell script that read values from a text file and place them in a script local variables.

For example the input file looks like:

```
input.txt
PARAM1=VALUE1
PARAM2=VALUE2
PARAM3=VALUE3
```

In the script I would like to place the values into three different variables like:

```
echo %variable1%
echo %variable2%
echo %variable3%
```

The output will be:

```
value1
value2
value3
```

I started the script like:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in ("input.txt") do set %%G=%%H  echo %G%
```

Please provide me some insights or ideas

Comment: I dont see anything posh related?

Comment: @JaquelineVanek "Posh"? You mean "PowerShell"? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to read values from a file and assign them to script local variables.

> ```
> @echo off
> setlocal
> for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in ("input.txt") do set %%G=%%H  echo %G%
> ```

Your batch file is close, but need a couple of tweaks:

1. In order to read the **contents** of `input.txt` in the `for` loop you need to `type` the file.
2. You have a mistake in your `echo` command, it should be `%%G` not `%%H`.

---

#### To display the variable names

**test.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
setlocal
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in ('type input.txt') do (set %%G=%%H && echo %%G)
endlocal
```

**Example usage:**

```
F:\test>type input.txt
PARAM1=VALUE1
PARAM2=VALUE2
PARAM3=VALUE3

F:\test>test
PARAM1
PARAM2
PARAM3
```

---

#### To display the **values** of the variables, replace `echo %%G` with `echo %%H`

**test.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
setlocal
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in ('type input.txt') do (set %%G=%%H && echo %%H)
endlocal
```

**Example usage:**

```
F:\test>type input.txt
PARAM1=VALUE1
PARAM2=VALUE2
PARAM3=VALUE3

F:\test>test
VALUE1
VALUE2
VALUE3
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) - Display the contents of one or more text files.

Answer (score 2):

The code is almost okay except for:

- `usebackq` option is needed if you specify the input file in doublequotes
- `echo %G%` should be either `echo !%%G!` and of course you'll need [setlocal enableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) at the start of the script or just before the loop.
  Or in your case you can simply print the value in `%%H`.
- use `()` for multi-line for-loops, otherwise separate the commands with `&` on the same line
- use quotes in `set` as shown in the code below in case the values have special characters.
- use `echo.` to print a line that could be empty (`/`,`:`,`(` may be used instead of dot)

```dos
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2 usebackq" %%G in ("input.txt") do (
    set "%%G=%%H"
    echo.%%H
)
```

Comment: Delayed expansion is not required in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the PowerShell syntax can be:

```
$InputText = Get-Content "C:\Temp\input.txt"

$i=0 #add inkrement 
ForEach ($line in $InputText)
{   
     $i++ #increment for variable numbers
     ($line -split "=")[1] | Set-Variable -Name ("variable$i")
}
#Show variables
$variable1
$variable2
#and so
```

More elegant than batch files :)